# Xcode reproducible crashes when creating i18n files

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization

I want to internationalize my app. Therefore I tried to create i18n key value files Localizable.strings. Following an I18n tutorial, I created a folder en.lproj (actually it already existed) and additionally I added a folder called de.lproj. Then I restarted the xcode project and as described in the tutorial I created  File->New->Strings file. But everytime I try creating a Localizable.strings file xcode crashes on creating it. I checked that the file was actually created but when I reopen my project in xcode these files are not shown under the group "Supporting Files". There is a file listed called Localizable.strings but I cannot differentiate between English and German i.e. there is no triangle on the left of the filename that indicates that another language property file exists. Did I forget something or is this actually a problem of Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Localizable.string` in XCode, choose "Make file localizable" in the files info window and add your languages. XCode will automatically create the `*.lproj` folders and the different versions of the file.